# Problems In Connection String with different Users in System for Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi this is my Connection String:

Windows Authentication:

```
<add name="strConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MURALI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ecowhisk28113;Integrated Security = True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;"/>
```

i run this applications in System's Administrator means working correctly but same application 
run in System's Users means I get This Error.

'Cannot open database "Ecowhisk28113" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MURALI\Murali'. '

I want know whether the connection string error or system settings problem...

please help to solve this bug....

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to Login to SSMS and grant the users that will be accessing the database proper permissions to the database.  You can check this by opening SSMS connecting to the SQL server expanding the Security folder right click on Logins and create a new Login for 'MURALI\Murali'and add the new Login access to the Ecowhish28113 database.  You depending on the type of access required you will need to add the login to the database roles in that DB as well.